# Extra field on sign-in selfasserted form is not rendered

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Trying to implement an invisible recaptcha on my sign-in selfasserted form.  I'm using the same technique that I did on my sign up but I noticed that my custom attribute is not rendered in the DOM and not shown (I will make this invisible).  I need **extension_captchaToken** to be part of the dom and have it populated by recaptcha through javascript. Can you let me know why? Thanks!

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            **<DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_captchaToken" Required="true" />**
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            **<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_captchaToken" />**
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [unifiedssp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#datauri) content definition template, or an [orchestration step type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#orchestrationsteps) of `CombinedSignInOrSignUp`, that will only render inputs for username/email and password.

You *could* use [claims resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers) to pass the `extension_captchaToken` claim to the site hosting your content definitions, as part of the URL. However, I think your content definition site would have to then incorporate that on its page server-side, client-side JavaScript runs on the merged B2C page not your content definition page.

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm using selfasserted 2.1.1 content definition.  Is there a way to pass my captcha token using claims resolvers if my client side script cannot access my custom attribute bec it is not part of the dom?

My sign up policy is using the same content definition and it renders my catpchaToken custom attribute.  I'm not sure why sign in is different....

Comment: The issue is almost answered here, so i will add, that when you are using the orchestration Type=CombinedSignInOrSignUp, you cannot render more fields on the page. This is why the [captcha sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/captcha-integration) uses Type=ClaimsExchange, and pure selfAsserted page to accomodate this requriement.

Comment: I finally get it. I was using unified, not selfasserted contentdefinition on my orchestration step. I can see the captcha field now. Thank you both!